NSIS installer failure. CMD Error Basic command not found
I try to call CMD to run the script after unpacking rEFInd
The manually executed script works, but if it does nisis fails with "bcdedit" not a valid command.
What is the problem?
This is my program at Nissis
OutFile "rEFIndInstall.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel admin
InstallDir "C:\rEFIndAjustes"
Section "MainSection" SEC01
CreateDirectory "$INSTDIR"  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR" File /r "F:\Documentos\LinuxMint\rEFIndAjustes\*.*"  ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c "$INSTDIR\Instalar.bat"'  Quit
SectionEnd

I tried using bcdedit absolute location and it still fails if run from nsis. Try using
%SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
in the script it should call but it still fails.
All of this works if you manually run the script, but not if you run it from nsis.

There are two operating system directories on 64-bit Windows: %SystemRoot%\System32 with 64-bit executables and libraries of Windows and %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64 with 32-bit executables and libraries of Windows. A 32-bit application like nsis starts always %ComSpec with option /c and the batch file name for processing a batch file. The environment variable ComSpec is defined with %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe. Read now WOW64 Implementation Details and also:

File System Redirector and Registry Keys Affected by WOW64 The file system redirector active for 32-bit nsis results in starting now 32-bit %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe. The 32-bit  cmd.exe searches now in your case for a file with name bcdedit in current directory and next in all directories of environment variable PATH which by Windows default begins with %SystemRoot%\system32.

But the file system redirector is also active for 32-bit cmd.exe. The search is redirected for that reason from %SystemRoot%\System32 containing 64-bit bcdedit.exe to %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64 which does not contain a file with name bcdedit. This executable is one of a small set of Windows commands which exist on 64-bit Windows only in 64-bit system directory. The solution is using following in the batch file: if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\bcdedit.exe (set "BCDEDIT=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\bcdedit.exe) else set "BCDEDIT=%SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe).

There can be used next %BCDEDIT% in one of the following lines to run either the 64-bit executable on 64-bit Windows independent from within 32-bit execution environment or run 32-bit executable on 32-bit Windows.  If rEFIndInstall.exe is written by yourself in C/C++/C# and this executable calls the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess for running bcdedit.exe, disable the file system redirection before calling CreateProcess as described by Microsoft on reference pages.

It is advisable to enable the file system redirection again after the CreateProcess call inside rEFIndInstall.exe for avoiding problems like when this executable later needs to dynamically load a library which of course must be the 32-bit version of the library and not the 64-bit version.

On 64-bit Windows, a 32-bit application gets its system32 folder redirected to the syswow64 folder by the File System Redirector.
You can turn off this redirection temporarily:
!include "x64.nsh"

Section
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
ExecWait '"$SysDir\cmd.exe" /K bcdedit.exe'
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
SectionEnd

Or if you want to stick with the 32-bit cmd.exe and only care about Vista+, you can use the backdoor:
InstallDir $Temp

Section "Create batch for example"
FileOpen $0 "$InstDir\SOTest.bat" w
FileWrite $0 "@echo off&setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION$\r$\n"
FileWrite $0 'for /F %%I in ("cmd.exe") do for %%A in (sysnative system32) do if exist "%%~dp$PATH:I..\%%A\bcdedit.exe" set bcdedit=%%~dp$PATH:I..\%%A\bcdedit.exe$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '%bcdedit%$\r$\n'
FileClose $0
SectionEnd

Section "Run it"
ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /k "$InstDir\SOTest.bat"'
SectionEnd

